# g:javascript in grails 3.1.9

Tags: javascript, grails

I am using g:javascript tag in gsp page to link my JS file in webapp/JS folder.
How ever it looks like grails is unable to pick the file. g:javascript seems to work in older version of grails.

On the other hand when I used g:external to link the JS file I was able to do it successfully.

Is there anything wrong with g.javascript in grails 3.1.9

Comment: From docs - "Will look in /appname/js directory." Are you sure the file in in the right place?

Comment: yes the js file in in correct dir only. but g:javascript not picking file. g:external is correctly picking the file

Answer (score 3):

Grails now uses the asset-pipeline plugin by default to manage static resources. The Grails docs are very out of date about this though, so you're much better off going directly to [the asset-pipeline docs](https://bertramdev.github.io/grails-asset-pipeline/), and in particular the docs for the [<asset:javascript> tag](https://bertramdev.github.io/grails-asset-pipeline/ref/Tags/javascript.html)